# How can I pass a custom server hostname using React?

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, fetch, command-line-arguments

I want to be able to pass a custom server hostname when running my React app to be used in the URL when I need to fetch data. The server is currently running on my local computer, so when I use *fetch(<URL>)*.

I've been using "http://localhost:...." which has worked perfectly. But I want to be able to have to pass a custom host name, such as my IP address, to be used in the URL (i.e., *http://ipaddress:...*).

I've tried starting my app like this:

```
serverhost=ipaddress npm start
```

And then in my *package.json* file

```
"scripts" : {
   "start": "react-scripts start $serverhost"
}
```

And in file *start.js* I can access *process.env.serverhost*, but I want to be able to access the hostname in the browser for my actual fetch calls. I don't want to set the hostname in "config" in *package.json* file or in an *.env* file, because it has to be able to change (I'm under the impression that this isn't possible). I just want to be able to access the server hostname given as an argument in the command line in my source files.

(I read somewhere about doing

```
REACT_APP_MY_VAR=test npm start
```

and then accessing it as

```
process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VAR
```

in the source files, but when I tried to fetch(<URL>), I got a bunch of failure to parse URL errors.)

I tried using REACT_APP variables and I no longer got parsing URL errors when fetching.

Comment: Create a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag, and send all your request relative to that base url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have .env file per environment and then set

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost.whatever
```

So for example .env.development

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost.whatever
```

.env.production

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://production.whatever
```

Usage of env variables is explained here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Eventually, you can add it to your script like

```
"scripts" : {
   "start": "REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost.whatever npm/yarn start"
   "start-production": "REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://production.whatever npm/yarn start"
}
```

If you don't really want to use above approaches at all then, assign your ip to some variable and add it to command to run your app

```
"scripts" : {
   "start": "REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=$(curl ifconfig.me) npm/yarn start"
   "start-other: "REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=$(echo MY_VAR_WITH_IP) npm/yarn start"
}
```

And then access your url from `process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT`

Comment: Thanks! I did some version of this that was a bit simpler but less functional and it worked - I'm hoping once my app leaves the developmental stage this will no longer be an issue because I won't have to run the server on my local computer

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag in your index.html that would set the base for all your requests from there on.

You can create the base tag dynamically by reading the [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and map your required path.

Note that all relative paths will be then mapped from your baseTag

An example would be something like this

```
<base href="https://www.dog.ceo/" />
```

And then create a request like this

```
fetch('api/breeds/list/all')
  .then( response => response.json() )
  .then( ({message}) => console.log( message ) );
```

The full address of that call would the be `https://www.dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all`